# Escaped double-quotes appear in string during debugging

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, escaping

I have a dictionary and I need to generate a JSON string by using `NSMutableArray`. Here is my code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
                     @"From":From,
                     @"To":To,
                     @"DepartureDate":DepartureDate,
                     };
[FinalArray addObject:dict];
```

Then I generate the JSON String like this:

```
NSError *error;
NSData * JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:FinalArray
                                                    options:kNilOptions
                                                      error:&error];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"jsonData=%@", jsonString);
```

Now output is on NSLog like this:

```
 [
  {
    "From": "city",
    "To": "city",
    "DepartureDate": "20160301"
  }
]
```

But while I'm debugging, at a breakpoint, the string appears with escaped double-quotes:

```
   "[{\"From\":\"city\",\"To\":\"city\",\"DepartureDate\":\"20160301\"}]"
```

Why is that?

Comment: The output is a valid JSON string.

Comment: Do you just want to pretty print the json?

Comment: while i'm debugging the response coming like this                        jsonString@"[{\"From\":\"DXB\",\"To\":\"MCT\",\"DepartureDate\":\"20160301\"}]"     but i need to Valid JSON format

Comment: How are you seeing that string?

Comment: through breakpoint i check the JsonString

Comment: No worry, the backslashes to escape the double quotes appear only in the console, actually they don't exist. You can prove it by converting the string back to an array.

Answer (score 1):

That's a stringified json object. My guess is that to allow the json to be shown in the console it's stringified, adding the escaped quotes. In your runtime the backslashes don't exist, they are only there to correctly display the json in the console.